# AQL Graph queries examples

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have trouble doing what i want with AQL and Graph queries.
I'd like to get some basics examples of AQL on a simple dataset.

For example:
Given a collection of **actors** and a collection of **movies**. And a **actIn** edges collection (with a **year** property) to connect the vertex.

[Actor] <- act in -> [Movie]

How could i get:

- All actors who acted in "movie1" OR "movie2"
- All actors who acted in both "movie1" AND "movie2" ?
- All actors who acted in 3 or more movies wit
- All common movies between "actor1" and "actor2" ?
- All actors who acted in 3 or more movies ?
- All movies where exactly 6 actors acted in ?
- The number of actors by movie ?
- The number of movies by actor ?
- The number of movies acted in between 2005 and 2010 by actor ?

This is simple queries but i don't get how to describe them using AQL.

Any help is welcome and if you have tuts or links to better understand how to get the job done, i'll be glad !

Thanks

Comment: We have some graph samples in: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB-Data - However, the mentioned screencast is a little out of date and doesn't use AQL but the webinterface. Did you already have a look at https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphOperations.html ? Its using a small city network as sample. If - what are your problems in understanding the examples? (so we may improve ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are right examples for AQL are sparse right now.
I have taken your questions here and created a recipe for the ArangoDB cookbook which should answer al of them.
Please have a look here: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-actors-and-movies.html

PS:
One of your queries is not complete:
`All actors who acted in 3 or more movies wit`
I did not know what to query for.

Comment: Oh my god! I was already falling in love with the product, now it is with the developpers. Thank you so much for this examples and for you reactivy.

Comment: I think the link is dead

Comment: The link is at this location: https://github.com/arangodb/Cookbook/blob/master/recipes/Graph/ExampleActorsAndMovies.md